# Change element attributes (datasets) in one operation - avoid Reflows

Tags: javascript, css, reflow

I'm trying to avoid `CSS Reflows`,
usually `DocumentFragment` is enough for my needs.

I have cases when I modify/add/remove `datasets`,
The problem is that each `dataset` require one operation which causes reflow..

`element.dataset` is a read only object, so I wondered how can I do it with only one reflow instead of 3 in this example?

```
element.dataset.a='1'
delete element.b
element.dataset.c='2'
```

Does replacing the element completely is the only way to achieve this?

Comment: After watching a video [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow) about CSS Reflows, I'm not sure they even know what they're talking about. Based on my logic of programming, I'm pretty sure the DOM is looped over, so anything more specific would actually prevent a paint up the DOM tree. Too many animations or transforms could be an issue. `DocumentFragment` is just used to append things to the `document`. I don't  recommend using it, because you can't attach Events to the nodes that are in the `DocumentFragment` before they are appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the dataset of an element will not cause a synchronous reflow. You can do it as many times as you'd like during the same task.

To test if something causes a reflow or not, you can use a CSS transition.
Going from a known state, then setting an intermediary state, triggering what should cause the reflow and finally setting back the original state.
If the tested action did trigger a reflow, then a new transition from the intermediary state to the final one will happen. If no reflow did happen, then no transition will happen.

```js
function testReflow(func) {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    const elem = document.querySelector(".reflow-tester");
    // set "intermediary" values
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    elem.style.transition = "none";
    try { func(elem); } catch(err) { rej(err) }
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.01s";

    // if the tested func does trigger a reflow
    // the transition will start from 1 to 0
    // otherwise it won't happen (from 0 to 0)    
    elem.addEventListener("transitionstart", (evt) => {
      res(true); // let the caller know the result
    }, { once: true });
    // if the transition didn't start in 100ms, it didn't cause a reflow
    setTimeout(() => res(false), 100);
  });
}

(async () => {
  // wait 1s before executing the tests to be sure we're not in weird first paint
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  // first testing with a well known reflow trigger
  const offsetWidth = await
  testReflow((elem)=>elem.offsetWidth);
  console.log("offsetWidth getter:", offsetWidth);
  // now with dataset
  const dataset = await testReflow((elem) => {
    elem.dataset.foo = "bar";
    elem.dataset.bar = "baz";
    elem.dataset.baz = "bla";
  });
  console.log("dataset:", dataset);
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
.reflow-tester {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="reflow-tester">Tester</div>
```